# refitting a model to the data during a backtest

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models

I built a back-tester for sports betting, I'm not sure whether to add a re-fitting feature. As in, while the back-tester is evaluating the model out of sample, should it be able to re-fit to data that was out of sample, but has already been evaluated by the back-tester?

::To be clear, I'm not suggesting fitting the model to data that hasn't been tested yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the test set and the train set are different, you can reuse the test set from the previous round. This is how cross-validation is usually done.

In addition, after you verify your model, you can refit your model with all the data you have. In this way, you can reduce the model variance of your final model.